# Matching words with special characters in a MySQL full-text natural language search

Tags: mysql, mariadb, full-text-search, special-characters

I have a database containing a list of songs and I want to use a full-text natural language search to allow users to get results that appear to be sorted by relevance to the search string in a more natural way.

This works great for the vast majority of cases, but I found that this doesn't seem to work for certain songs. For example if I try to search for the song "T.N.T" by "AC/DC", both the artist and song name are short and split with special characters that seem to confuse the search.

This is the search query I am using.

```
SELECT DISTINCT artist, title, album, year
FROM songs
WHERE MATCH(artist, title, album) AGAINST('AC/DC' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
LIMIT 20
```

This returns no results when I search for "T.N.T." or "AC/DC", or even "AC/DC T.N.T."

Here is an example of the row I am expecting to be returned from the search.
[image]

Does anyone know how I can get a natural language search to work in this instance?